# What is the best way to resume training with a different learning rate in pytorch lightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I want to train a model in two stages. The first one is a pre-training with teacher forcing, and the second one is a regular training (without teacher forcing). The difference here is that the model is instantiated with `use_teacher_forcing=True` in the first case and `use_teacher_forcing=False` in the latter.

To do so, I currently run two trainings, where the second training resumes from the first trainings checkpoint, by passing the last checkpoint to the lightning trainer.

Regarding the learning rate, I want to decay it over several milestones as well in pre-training as well as in regular training. For instance, if I use 5 epochs of pre-training and 5 epochs of training, I want the learning rate to be as follows:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1e-4 | 1e-4 | 1e-5 | 1e-5 | 1e-6 | 1e-4 | 1e-4 | 1e-5 | 1e-5 | 1e-6 |

However, I cannot find a way reset the learning rate to its initial value at the beginning of the regular training, since the scheduler is also loaded from the checkpoint.

Is there a way to do this?
I am using torch 1.9.0 und pytorch-lightning 1.3.8 and am not able to upgrade to later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following solution.

Apparently, it's not that hard to implement and use a custom learning rate scheduler. I'll leave the code here in case anybody stumbles upon the same problem.

```
class MultiStepLRWithReset(_LRScheduler):
def __init__(self, optimizer, milestones, reset_epochs, reset_lr_to=None, gamma=0.1, last_epoch=-1, verbose=False):
    full_milestones = milestones
    for reset_epoch in reset_epochs:
        full_milestones += [m + reset_epoch for m in milestones]
    self.milestones = Counter(full_milestones)
    self.reset_epochs = reset_epochs
    self.reset_lr_to = reset_lr_to
    self.gamma = gamma
    super(MultiStepLRWithReset, self).__init__(optimizer, last_epoch, verbose)

def get_lr(self):
    if not self._get_lr_called_within_step:
        warnings.warn("To get the last learning rate computed by the scheduler, "
                      "please use `get_last_lr()`.", UserWarning)
    if self.last_epoch in self.reset_epochs:
        if self.reset_lr_to is None:
            return [group['initial_lr'] for group  in self.optimizer.param_groups]
        else:
            return [self.reset_lr_to for _ in self.optimizer.param_groups]
    if self.last_epoch not in self.milestones:
        return [group['lr'] for group in self.optimizer.param_groups]
    return [group['lr'] * self.gamma ** self.milestones[self.last_epoch]
            for group in self.optimizer.param_groups]
```

You will have to create a LRScheduler for the entire training as it will not be reinstantiated for the second training stage if all the pytorch training components are loaded from their last checkpoint.